# Java Multithreading web scraper that extracts data continuously at every second while allowing consumer to retrieve data

Tags: java, multithreading, web-scraping

I am working on a multi-threaded based Web application using Java.

I have two threads inside that application, a web Scraper and a thread to perform some computation( similar to a producer and consumer). The Scraper continuously reads the data from a third party API(world population that updates at each second). The other thread (consumer) continuously tries to retrieve data from scraper and computes the fastest changing rate in every minute.

My question is that the **scraper** needs to extract data at every second continuously. When the consumer retrieves data, it needs to lock the **scraper**'s variable(eg.buffer) where data is recorded. However, that may prevent the **scraper** from recording data at each second continuously. Is there a method that allows the consumer to retrieve data without preventing the **scraper** from extracting data at every continuous second?

Comment: Sounds like you may want a [Circular Buffer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2880/Circular-Buffer).

Comment: Copy the scraped data to a new data structure and return to the user. That way the user can access data as of the time of their request, and the scraper can still retrieve new data.

Comment: You want to get an update of the world's population every second and find the second when the population grows the most? That's a rather harebrained scheme IMO. Do you think some central authority is informed within 0.1 seconds every time someone is born in a village in Mongolia? Whatever data source you're using will be essentially a linear estimate of the population. The only variation in observed growth rate will be caused by rounding errors and varying delays in the network, not by actual variations in population growth.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the BlockingQueue Java doc. Implementations are threadsafe so your producer and consumer thread can safely communicate with eacher over the queue.
If you are worried about "missing a beat" when handing over the scraper result to the consumer, then start a new scraper thread every second. Then, if one scraper thread has to wait when handing over a result, it does not affect the scraping of other threads. If the scraping result structure is timestamped you can deal with possible out of order messages on the consumer level. Or on the queue level by using a PriorityQueue. The PriorityQueue is not threadsafe though.